# Map(iterable) alternative for IE 11

Tags: javascript, typescript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, polyfills

Unfortunately I have to support IE11.

I create my map with this code (polyfill for .entries already used):

`const map = new Map(Object.entries(array));`

but because of IE11 not supporting the *iterable* constructor the Map is empty.

I couldn't find a polyfill or anything else for this. Does anyone have an easy way of fixing this?

Afterwards I use the `map` like this:

```
  map.forEach((maps: ITopoInterface[], key: string) => {
    maps.findIndex((t: ITopoInterface) => {
     //do stuff
    });
  });
```

Comment: How have you added the `Map` class to IE11? Doesn't it support getting stuff from an array?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Babel transpile Map to be usable in IE11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42491429/does-babel-transpile-map-to-be-usable-in-ie11)

Comment: What about [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-map)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say this is empty:

```
const map = new Map(Object.entries(array));
```

Have you tried just adding the values yourself?

```
const map = new Map();
Object.entries(array).forEach(entry => {
    map.set(entry[0], entry[1]);
});
```

Comment: this works. I'll think as long as I have to support IE11 I'll do it this way. Thanks

Comment: I suggest you mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.