# Function does not change the text of an element in IE10-11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am creating a layout with IE10-11 support. Most of my functions work, but the .text jQuery method does nothing. When I click on the button on my page, the text of some elements should change based on the passed argument to my function. The code:

```js
const currenciesChars = new Map([
  ['rub', '₽'],
  ['usd', '$'],
  ['eur', '€']
])

const currenciesNote = new Map([
  ['rub', 'Руб'],
  ['usd', 'USD'],
  ['eur', 'EUR']
])

function changeCurrency(currency) {
  $(".currency").text(currenciesChars.get(currency))
  $(".currency-note").text(currenciesNote.get(currency))
}

changeCurrency('usd');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="currency"></div>
<div class="currency-note"></div>
```

The console does not produce a single error. However, the function works if you add `alert (123)` to it, you can verify this.
What is the problem of my code?

Comment: What are these elements? Provide an [mcve]

Comment: `Map` is not supported in IE10. [`new Map(arguments)` is not supported in IE11](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-Map_constructor_arguments).

Comment: That's a good point. Have you polyfilled `Map`? Did you fail to tell us about error messages on the console of the developer tools?

Comment: You can see the effect of `new Map(arguments)` not being supported in IE11 by visiting https://jsfiddle.net/tz1w5gmx/1/embedded/result,css,html,js with IE11 and look at the console. It should log `[object Object]` for the `Map` variable, and a function for the `Map.get`, but then `undefined` for the result of the `Map.get(key)` call. Basically, IE11 creates an empty `Map` when called with arguments. No errors, just empty :(. I don't have a VM with IE10 handy to test that.

Comment: For workarounds in IE11, see [Map(iterable) alternative for IE 11](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59375015/215552)

Answer (score 0):

As commented above, new Map(arguments) is not supported in IE11. You need to use [@babel/polyfill](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill) to polyfill it in IE:

1. Install @babel/polyfill by running the following command:

   ```
   npm install --save @babel/polyfill
   ```
2. In the @babel/polyfill npm release, there's a file `@babel/polyfill/dist/polyfill.js`. You could include it before all your compiled Babel code. You can either prepend it to your compiled code or include it in a `<script>` before it.
3. To make your code working in IE 10, you also need to change `const` to `var`.

The working code sample is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="node_modules/@babel/polyfill/dist/polyfill.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="currency"></div>
    <div class="currency-note"></div>
    <script>           
        var currenciesChars = new Map([
            ['rub', '₽'],
            ['usd', '$'],
            ['eur', '€']
        ])

        var currenciesNote = new Map([
            ['rub', 'Руб'],
            ['usd', 'USD'],
            ['eur', 'EUR']
        ])

        function changeCurrency(currency) {
            $(".currency").text(currenciesChars.get(currency))
            $(".currency-note").text(currenciesNote.get(currency))
        }    
        changeCurrency('usd');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```